# ng-options selects element at index 0, when ng-model is null (only after digest loop)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a `<select>` for which I use `ng-options` to fill the options. The model of the select is a string. I fill the string with a route parameter, before the options are asynchronously loaded.

In the controller:

```
$scope.selection = $routeParams.id; // optional, so defaults to undefined
$scope.items = [{id: "uuid1", name: "item 1"}, {id: "uuid2", name: "item2"}];
```

In the template:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
    <option value="" disabled>-- please select --</options>
</select>
```

The rendered html looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
    <option value="" disabled>-- please select --</options>
    <option value="0">Item 1</options>
    <option value="1">Item 2</options>
</select>
```

When I go to the page without the id route param, "-- please select --" is correctly selected. **When I do something else on the page, the select-box suddenly selects "Item 1" but `$scope.selection` is still `undefined`.**

I suspect that angular checks if the `undefined` value equals the value of the option "0", so it selects it.

**How can I prevent this?**

I use angular 1.2.17 (for backwards compatibility reasons), but I'v also tested this with 1.3.0.

Comment: please create a fiddle or plunker of the issue you are getting ...

Comment: You should initialize the selection value in your controller with blank.

Comment: @Anita initializing it blank ("" or null) doesn't help.

Comment: I guess its not the problem with select,its someting else on page which is creating problem. It would be better if u'll provide fiddle/plunker

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$scope.selection = $scope.items[$routeParams.id];`

Official angular [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/)